# Reverse bool value in binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, binding, windows-phone

I have a `TextBlock` like this:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsOnline, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

`boolToVisibility` returns `Visible` if `IsOnline` is true. But in a situation I want textblock be `Collapsed` if `IsOnline` is true.

I can make another converter which acts in reverse, but I want to know isn't it possible to do that in XAML with current converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially use a ConverterParameter value to determine whether to invert the output, for instance:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsOnline, ConverterParameter=true, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

And in the converter itself:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool invertOuput = false;

    if (parameter != null) {
        bool.TryParse((string)parameter, out invertOuput)
    }

    // TODO: Converter logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, you'll have to make another converter, although, your converter (not reverese) already exists:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx